# Good resources that talk about geodesically convex sets for riemannian manifolds?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, manifolds, geodesics

Are there any good resources that talk about geodesically convex sets, and in particular convex hulls, for riemannian manifolds? I’ve been wanting to learn more about them, their geometry and properties, theorems about them, etc. I’m suprised to see I can’t find much resources on them, but maybe I’m not looking in the right places. I’ve found a few good ones though, like this, but I can’t find much discussion about them beyond giving a general definition.

I also want to emphasize that I am not looking for the convex hull in the ambient space, but within the manifold.